# Busqueda en Google Maps API Android

Tags: android-studio, google-maps, buscador

Estoy creando una aplicación que utiliza Google Maps, he implementado un cuadro de búsqueda, el problema es que al momento de hacer la búsqueda esta la hace en todo el mundo. 
Lo que quiero hacer es que esta búsqueda este limitada solamente a mi ciudad a donde esta enfocada la aplicación. 
Por ejemplo al ingresar el nombre de una calle únicamente busque la calle en mi ciudad y no en todo el mundo. Este es el codigo con el que hago la busqueda:

```
editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);
    go = (Button) findViewById(R.id.go);
    type = (Button) findViewById(R.id.type);

    go.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String data = editText.getText().toString();
            List<Address> list = null;

            if(!data.equals("") || data != null ){
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(Ruta1Unidad.this);


                try{
                   list = geocoder.getFromLocationName(data,1);
                }catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Address address = list.get(0);
                LatLng marker2 = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(),  address.getLongitude());
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marker2).title("Prueba"));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(marker2, 13f));

            }
        }
    });
```